# Add a row total to a view

Tags: sql, view

new to SQL and I'm looking to do some work with income per month and quarterly/annual totals.

I have a mock view which pulls information from a company table (giving us company ID and CompanyName) and an income table (giving us the remaining 4 columns) like this:

```
CompanyID |CompanyName |IncomeType  |Jan   |Feb   |Mar
-----------------------------------------------------------    
1         |Big Stuff   |Cars        |1000  |200   |500 
2         |Huge Stuff  |Lorries     |2000  |4000  |5000
```

What I'd like is to be able to sum Jan+Feb+Mar as a `Total` column per `CompanyID`.

I'm having problems with including the sum(J+F+M) as first SQL asks for a group on the `companyID`, then once that's grouped, it asks for grouping on `CompanyName` and so on.

Any help gratefully received.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?  Also listing sample data from each table and expected results using this sample data would help.  As well as how the tables relate.  I'm not sure if the problem is due to how data exists in the income table or if it's a a simple misunderstanding of how aggregates (sum,min,max,avg, etc) work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `sum()`, unless you have an aggregation query already.  So, something like:

```
select c.companyID, c.CompanyName, i.IncomeType, i.Jan, i.Feb, i.Mar,
       (i.Ja + i.Feb + i.Mar) as Total
from company c join
     income i
     on c.companyid = i.companyid;
```

Comment: Great stuff, thanks!  Misunderstanding of aggregates etc @xQbert.  So to take this to the next step, if I have: (J+F+M) as Total1 and (A+M+J) as Total2, I've tried Total1+Total2, but it didn't like it.  How do we get a total of the totals :)

Comment: @Stu412 . . . You have to use the base columns . . . `(J + F + M + A + M + J)` or use a subquery/CTE.  You can't use a column alias in the same `select` where it is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this...

```
SELECT C.companyID, C.CompanyName, C.IncomeType, sum(Jan) J , sum(Feb) F, 
       sum(Mar) M, sum(Jan+Feb+Mar) as Total
FROM company C
INNER JOIN Income I
  on  C.CompanyID = I.CompanyId
GROUP BY C.companyID, C.CompanyName, C.IncomeType
```